# Weird python situation in vim

Tags: python, vim

I use vim 8.1, under Windows 7 x64.
Python is installed and the version is **3.7.5**

When I `echo has('python')` in vim, it returns `1`.
But when I `:python import sys`, it says this:

> E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could
>   not be loaded.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/FAQ#when-using-the-vim-plugin-i-got-e887-sorry-this-command-is-disabled-the-pythons-site-module-could-not-be-loaded